# Coded UI testing, swapping tabs and unable to find controls

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

I have a c# coded UI script, that opens a page, enters a value into a field, clicks an image, clicks a link to open another page in a new tab, enters some data, switches back to the first tab, enters more data BUT cannot find the button 2nd time around.

```
var browser = BrowserWindow.Launch("...url...");
var edit = new HtmlEdit(browser);
edit.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlEdit.PropertyNames.Id, "name");
edit.Text = "Bob";
var img = new HtmlImage(browser);
img.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlImage.PropertyNames.Id, "requestImg");
Mouse.Click(img);
var link = new HtmlHyperlink(browser);
link.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlHyperlink.PropertyNames.InnerText, "newTab");
Mouse.Click(link);
var place= new HtmlEdit(browser);
place.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlEdit.PropertyNames.Id, "place");
place.Text = "Here";
Keyboard.SendKeys("^{Tab}");
edit = new HtmlEdit(browser);
edit.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlEdit.PropertyNames.Id, "name");
edit.Text = "Sue";
img = new HtmlImage(browser);
img.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlImage.PropertyNames.Id, "requestImg");
Mouse.Click(img);
Playback.Wait(12000);
... do more stuff
```

Everything works as expected, except that last attempt to click on the image. There are no error messages/exceptions from the last attempt to click on the image, and the subsequent code runs, but fails as the click event has not worked.
Why would the code that changes text boxes work after tabbing back, but not the clicking on the image tab? I've tried adding in browser.Find(), browser.Refresh(), img.Find() - none improve the situation

Comment: You can use the reflection to get the image and then perform the click event

Comment: Shyam - what do you mean by "use the reflection"?

Comment: Reflection is the reverse process for anything. Refer this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection

Answer (score 0):

A solution, although I'm looking for a better one...

using img.Drawhighlight(); a blue box of the right size is being drawn, but not in the right position - its too high up the screen and too far left. My laptop has a native 3200x1800 screen and so I run the browser at 250%.

Before creating the second tab, the coded UI test clicks in the right place.
After creating the second tab, the coded UI test has got the wrong resolution, and can't click on the image.
The workaround is to run the browser as 3200x1800, 100%. The Mouse.Click(img); then works, but I can't quite read the screen.
Setting the display resolution to 1920x1080 and 100% results in text that is more legible, but the coded UI test doesn't find the button.
So works for now, but would be even better if I could tell the test/browser would remember the screen resolution, and so I'm going to look into that.